# WPF ItemSource returns null

Tags: wpf, datagrid, ienumerable, itemsource

I have a named class

```
public class testClass
{
    public testClass(string showCode, string urn)
    {
        ShowCode = showCode;
        URN = urn;
    }

    public string ShowCode { get; set; }
    public string URN { get; set; }
}
```

I create an ArrayList, add to the list and bind it to a wpf datagrid

```
ArrayList l = new ArrayList();
l.Add(new testClass("ose11", "7016463"));
this.grdTestData.ItemsSource = l;
```

This displays just what I want in the datagrid.

Now I want to get the datagrid's data back and iterate throught it

```
IEnumerable<testClass> t = this.grdTestData.ItemsSource as IEnumerable<testClass>;
```

..but '**t**' is null!  !! this is the problem !!

This is the datagrid definition:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,66,0,48" Name="grdTestData" Width="200" CanUserAddRows="True" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ShowCode" Binding="{Binding ShowCode}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="URN"  Binding="{Binding Path=URN}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Please use proper code formatting, its difficult to read your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ItemsSource is not null, it's just that `ArrayList` does not implement `IEnumerable<testClass>`, and therefore the cast you perform returns `null`. If you use

```
var list = (IEnumerable<testClass>) datagrid.ItemsSource;
```

you will get an error saying that this cast is not valid.

If you use a `List<testClass>` instead of `ArrayList` for the source, the cast will be valid and not return null.

If you don't wish to use a generic collection, then cast it to `ArrayList` or `IEnumerable (non-generic)`  instead, if you wish to have an interface.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, that's enabled me to put it right. Solved.